# how to create instances of StreamBuilder<UserModel>

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have this part in my code that I want to repeat throughout the project and I wish to just be able to call this function elsewhere, but the problem is that you need to pass `snapshot.data` to the `widget` down the tree,, any ideas how to do that ?

```
Widget UserStreamBuilderShortcut(BuildContext context, Widget widget){

  final _user = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);

  return

    StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
      stream: UserProvider(userID: _user.userID).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData == false){
          return LoadingFullScreenLayer();
        } else {
          UserModel userModel = snapshot.data; // cant pass this to instances of UserStreamBuilderShortcut Widget
          return
            widget; // in instances of this UserStreamBuilderShortcut we need to be able to pass snapshot.data here
        }
      },
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a builder parameter for this

```
// define a Function type that takes a BuildContext and UserModel
// and returns a Widget
typedef UserModelWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(
  BuildContext context,
  UserModel userModel,
);

// pass it as a parameter in the shortcut function
Widget UserStreamBuilderShortcut({
  BuildContext context,
  UserModelWidgetBuilder builder,
}) {
  final _user = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);

  return StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
    stream: UserProvider(userID: _user.userID).userData,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
        return LoadingFullScreenLayer();
      } else {
        UserModel userModel = snapshot.data;
        return builder(context, userModel);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Now you can call this as follows:

```
UserStreamBuilderShortcut(
  context: context,
  builder: (context, UserModel userModel) {
    return Container(); // create widget with UserModel
  },
),
```

Comment: Perfect Professional super awesome solution
Thank you Master Coder,
I would like to name you the Master of Code, The King of snippets and the lord of Flutter widgets

Comment: @RagehElAzzazy hahaha, just glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Provider package you can call its stream arguments from its child widgets.

Parent Widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<BrewList>.value(
      value: Database().brewList,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: BrewListTile(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Child Widget that has access to the stream.

```
class _BrewListState extends State<BrewList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final brews = Provider.of<List<Brew>>(context) ?? [];
    return Text(brews[0].text);
```